# Itaipu Dam - can you see the lighting show right after the catamaran tour?

Tags: brazil, iguazu-falls

I want to go on the [Kattamaram Sunset tour](https://ingressos.turismoitaipu.com.br/p/itaipu-kattamaram-por-do-sol) at the Itaipu Dam on Friday, then see the [lighting show](https://ingressos.turismoitaipu.com.br/p/itaipu-iluminada).

It's not clear if you can do these in the same evening: the catamaran tour starts at 5pm and lasts for "2h45min total", and the lighting show is listed to start at 7:30pm and last for 90 minutes. I wouldn't mind missing the first 15 minutes (probably a documentary film), plus sunset isn't until 7:30pm anyway in December.

But I don't know if they close admission for the lighting show by a certain time, or if there's no bus after 7:30 etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've emailed Itaipu at info@turismoitaipu[dot]com.br and it turns out the question is moot: they're canceling the catamaran tour (both the day and sunset tours) after TODAY (Dec 18, 2019). What are the odds.

> Unfortunately today is the last day of Kattamaram ride, after the ride today will be disabled and no plans to return.
>
> May make the tour of the Itaipu Enlightened, I suggest that you purchase in advance via our website to guarantee your reservation:
> https://ingressos.turismoitaipu.com.br/p/itaipu-iluminada

[image: No more Kattamaram tour]

**However**

1. There seems to be an active "Katttamaram II" in the area. I did see a catamaran on Dec 20, 2019.
2. The question is still interesting to those who want to take the day tour (Panoramico or Especial), because the last admission is at 16:40, and there will be a gap until 19:30, when the buses depart for the lighting show (which IMO in itself was a bit disappointing, save for the fireworks and the concert).